# Problems installing SUPEE-6788 patch on 1.9.2.1

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches, ce-1.9.2.1, supee-6788

Having issues while installing the SUPEE 6788 patch.

First issue was I was using a custom edited .htaccess file. I've now replaced with the stock version for 1.9.2.1 but still getting errors as seen below:

> ```
> root@cloud [/home/--removed--/public_html]# bash PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.2.1_v1-2015-10-26-11-38-41.sh
> Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
> ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
>
> patching file .htaccess
> patching file .htaccess.sample
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block/Collection.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable/Collection.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Variable.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.1-1.6.1.2.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit/Form.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Grid.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit/Form.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Grid.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/BlockController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/VariableController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/adminhtml.xml
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/File.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/UnserializeArray.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Changeforgotten.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Resetpassword.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Product/Type.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Resource/Attribute/Collection.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Item/Collection.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/DownloadController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Resource/Coupon/Collection.php
> patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/admin.xml
> patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml
> patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
> patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
> patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
> patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/layout/customer.xml
> patching file app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/customer.xml
> patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/customer.xml
> patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
> patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
> patching file cron.php
> The next patch would delete the file dev/tests/functional/.htaccess,
> which does not exist!  Assume -R? [n]
> Apply anyway? [n]
> Skipping patch.
> 1 out of 1 hunk ignored
> patching file errors/processor.php
> patching file lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
> patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
> patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrKey.php
> patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
> patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Bool.php
> patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Dbl.php
> patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Int.php
> patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Str.php
> patching file lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php
> patching file lib/Zend/Xml/Security.php
> root@cloud [/home/--removed--/public_html]#
> ```

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the file 'dev/tests/functional/.htaccess'

In order to make the patch finish, you need to have that file (with it's data from 1.9.2.1) so that it can delete it. Weird, I know.

Comment: Strange why would i be missing that file ? ill try add it now

Comment: Strange ive just checked the stock 1.9.2.1 files and indeed there is a dev folder that somehow isnt on my server, im just uploading the files now and will retry the patch ! Thankyou so much

Comment: The `dev` folder has been added for creating a development testing environment for Magento. It probably was removed after installation as extraneous server filler, much like some admins will remove the `downloader` folder from live servers for security reasons.