# 6788 patch error

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches, supee-6788

I applied 6788 patch to my magento 1.9.1.1 instance, while i applying patch it gets like this

```
      PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2015-10-26-11-45-55.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2015-10-26-11-45-55.sh: 127: not found

PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2015-10-26-11-45-55.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2015-10-26-11-45-55.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2015-10-26-11-45-55.sh: 25: PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2015-10-26-11-45-55.sh: 0: not found
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
-e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file .htaccess
Hunk #1 FAILED at 207.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file .htaccess.sample
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block/Collection.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable/Collection.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Variable.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.1-1.6.1.2.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit/Form.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Grid.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit/Form.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Grid.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/BlockController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/VariableController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/adminhtml.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/File.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 131.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/UnserializeArray.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Changeforgotten.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Resetpassword.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Product/Type.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Resource/Attribute/Collection.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Item/Collection.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/DownloadController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Resource/Coupon/Collection.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/admin.xml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/js/cookie.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
can't find file to patch at input line 2567
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/default/iphone/layout/customer.xml app/design/frontend/default/iphone/layout/customer.xml
|index dd384fc..2da07a4 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/default/iphone/layout/customer.xml
|+++ app/design/frontend/default/iphone/layout/customer.xml
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 2592
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/customer.xml app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/customer.xml
|index fb94b09..42a6574 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/customer.xml
|+++ app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/customer.xml
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 2617
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/customer.xml app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/customer.xml
|index 271fc88..60deace 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/customer.xml
|+++ app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/customer.xml
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 2642
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
|index e6e9338..5fd3931 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
|+++ app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 2655
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
|index b4cb9ff..72278f3 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
|+++ app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file cron.php
checking file errors/processor.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrKey.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Bool.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Dbl.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Int.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Str.php
checking file lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php
checking file lib/Zend/Xml/Security.php
```

how to solve this and how to check patch installed or not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems installing SUPEE-6788 patch on 1.9.2.1](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88050/problems-installing-supee-6788-patch-on-1-9-2-1)

Comment: where we get dev/tests/functional/.htaccess - Teja

Comment: you can find that file at your root folder

Comment: i didnt find this folder

Comment: my magento version i s1.9.1.1 @TejabhagavanKollepara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The patch tells you that it cannot find files in

```
> app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template
```

The `default/iphone` theme was part of Magento 1.7 and the patch also contains security fixes for this theme. You have probably removed the theme that is making the patch fail.

#### Solution:

- Download Magento 1.7.0.2 and copy `app/design/default/iphone` into your installation.
- Apply the patch
- Remove the iphone theme again (or just leave it there)